# Proof of Dini's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading Theorem 7.13(Dini's Theorem) in Walter Rudin's book.The theorem states that if K is a compact subset of a metric space (X,d),  $\{f_n\}_n\subset \mathcal C(K)$  is a decreasing sequence of functions (i.e. $f_n(x)\ge f_{n+1}(x) ,\forall x\in K$ ) that $\mathit converges$ $\mathit pointwise$ to $f\in \mathcal C(K)$ ,then $\{f_n\}_n$ $\mathit converges$ $\mathit uniformly$ to f in K.

The proof defines $g_n:=f_n-f$ and the sets $K_n:= \{x\in K : g_n(x)\ge ε \}=g^{-1}([ε,+ \infty)) $. Because of the pointwise convergence of $\{f_n\}_n$ we get that $\{g_n\}_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ . Afterwards, $[ε,+\infty)$ is a closed set and $g_n$ is continuous so $K_n$ is a closed set (because g inverts closed sets to closed sets).Then, $g_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$,so  $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n=\varnothing$$
Because of that
we derive that $K_{n_0}=\varnothing$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$,so

$(\exists n_0\in \mathbb N) :(\forall n\ge n_0)\ 0\le g_n(x) \le ε$

My question is why the book says that $g_n(x)\ge 0$.Yes,that would be enough for the proof to end,but I don't understand how we get that.By definition of $\mathit uniform$ $\mathit convergence$ we should have shown that $|g_n|\le ε$. How do we get $g_n(x)\ge 0$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dini's Theorem Proof on the Reals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187695/dinis-theorem-proof-on-the-reals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(f_n(x))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing and since $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$, then $f(x)\leqslant f_n(x)$ for each $x\in K$. In other words, $f_n(x)-f(x)\geqslant0$ for each $x\in K$. But then, since$$g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)-f(x),$$$g(x)\geqslant0$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4187695/809021)

Comment: I see.It is then as in decreasing/increasing sequences,that they have as a limit the infimum/supremum of the set containing the terms of the sequence. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.